# Why is the emacs-25.1-2 binary for Windows so big?

Tags: microsoft-windows, install, binary

[image]

why is it so big? almost twice the size of 25.1
what's new with it?

Comment: Isn't this the one which comes with WebKit inside?

Comment: @wvxvw didn't know that. Why does emacs bundle webkit?

Comment: @wvxvw didn't know that. Why does emacs bundle webkit?

Comment: (1) I don't know if it does this on Windows (this is configurable during the build). (2) I'm not an authoritative source... but, my guess is this is an effort to modernize Emacs, to replace `eww`, `w3m` and such... Gnus can also use WebKit to render emails.

Comment: @wvxvw It is my understanding that eww is supposed to be modern.

Comment: AFAIK, the webkit embedding is only for GTK builds (i.e., not Windows), and wouldn't affect executable size anyway since it runs in a separate process.

Comment: Well, then I really don't know... but, just a wild guess: maybe on Windows they statically linked WebKit? Also, `eww` is... a modern piece of code, but in terms of how modern web browsers look, it's rather... well, not modern :)

Comment: Is it an actual release ? Perhaps there's some debugging information left in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's compiled with different compiler options to address performance issues.
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-11/msg00284.html